# Returning integer value

Tags: ios6, integer, automatic-ref-counting, instance-variables, nslog

I am writing ann app in Objective-C iOS6 ARC.
This is a snippet of code:

```
header file:
@interface Chapter : NSObject


-(void) addPageCount:(int) pCount;
-(int)getPageCount;
@end

//implementation
#import "Chapter.h"
@interface Chapter()
{

    int pageCount;
}
@end
-(void)addPageCount:(int) pCount
{
    pageCount = pCount;
}


//testing

 NSLog(@"%d", [chapter getPageCount]);

Returns -1073750816 once I pass 100.
```

What is the prob?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found. At some point I have been sending a pointer value instead of integer